# Quickly remove duplicate strings from VBA Collection

Tags: string, vba, list, collections

```
Dim MyCollection As VBA.Collection
Set MyCollection = New VBA.Collection

For i = MyCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
    For j = (i - 1) To 1 Step -1
        If MyCollection(i) = MyCollection(j) Then
            MyCollection.Remove i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

There are currently 8000 e-mail entries in MyCollection. I would like to remove redundant elements from this large list, but faster.

How can I accelerate this code?

Comment: 8000 thousand?  So **8 million**?  Your question is hard to understand, but the best way to avoid duplicates is to use a dictionary object instead of a collection when initially storing the data.  What kind of data is stored and how long does your method take for the 8 million records?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Removing duplicates from a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355335/vba-removing-duplicates-from-a-collection)

Comment: Not 8 million. It's a typo. Made edits to my question. The gist of the question is that the list is large which creates a lag, hence would like to accelerate the process. Is there a better code for it?

Answer (score 0):

I have advice, it's quite simple and must cases it must be effectiver.

Of cause with some "buts" and main "but":

- you must have enough memory
- delete count must be high enough

#### Advice: don't delete element by element

Instead of delete: create **new collection** without unneeded records.

After that: drop old collection as whole.

Comment: Everything depends on ratios: the bigger your delete count  the more effective will be recreation of list. Obviously you will have less inserts and instead of deletes you will do **nothing**. 
On the other hand:  if you delete laughable count of rows - than delete is not a problem at all, problem is filtering.

Comment: Very kind of you for providing an idea. I am not sure of the meaning of "creating a new collection without unneeded records." My code actually tries to do exactly that! How about this: divide the list into many smaller ones and remove redundancies for each list. Then merge the lists into one big list, and remove redundancies for this merged list. Would this be faster?

Comment: And about dividing into smaller and smaller datasets: modern RAM subsystems  don't like a lot small operations, much better when you combine many little operations into thick batches.